# Remove a variable if a value is false

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So, I juste created a script like that

```js
const rolelog = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(newRole.guild.name, newRole.guild.iconURL())
    .addField('Edit of', newRole.name)
    .addField("Name before", oldRole.name, true)
    .addField("Name after", newRole.name,true)
    .addField("Position before", oldRole.position, true)
    .addField("Position after", newRole.position, true)
    .addField("Role color before", oldRole.hexColor, true)
    .addField("Role color after", newRole.hexColor, true)
    .setColor(newRole.hexColor)
    .setFooter("ID: "+newRole.id+" • "+date+" at "+time)
    var logs = bot.channels.cache.get(logchannel[newRole.guild.id].channel);
    if (logs){
        logs.send(rolelog)
    }
```

But I don't want all of this, I want to create a "auto edit embed" like this

if only the name change say this

```
output: Name before: W Name after: WO
```

if only the name change and the position say this

```
output: Name before: W Name after: WO
Position before: 0
Position after: 1
```

I don't want a huge script but a little script, he can understand if it's only the name changed, like the bot Koya if you see. Thanks you for your answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still edit the [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) after declaration.

```js
// const Discord = require('discord.js');

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor('GREEN');

if (1 + 1 === 2) embed.setTitle('1 + 1 = 2! Can you believe it?');
else embed.setTitle('1 + 1 =/= 2! I guess everything we know about math is wrong?');
```